# Behaviour of "eval" under "set -e" in conditional expression

Tags: posix, openbsd, eval

Consider the commands

```sh
eval false || echo ok
echo also ok
```

Ordinarily, we'd expect this to execute the `false` utility and, since the exit status is non-zero, to then execute `echo ok` and `echo also ok`.

In all the POSIX-like shells I use (`ksh93`, `zsh`, `bash`, `dash`, OpenBSD `ksh`, and `yash`), this is what happens, but things get interesting if we enable `set -e`.

If `set -e` is in effect, OpenBSD's `sh` and `ksh` shells (both derived from `pdksh`) will terminate the script when executing the `eval`. No other shell does that.

[POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01) that an error in a special built-in utility (such as `eval`) should cause the non-interactive shell to terminate.  I'm not entirely sure whether executing `false` constitutes "an error" (if it was, it would be independent of `set -e` being active).

The way to work around this seems to be to put the `eval` in a sub shell,

```sh
( eval false ) || echo ok
echo also ok
```

The question is whether I'm expected to have to do that in a POSIX-ly correct shell script, or whether it's a bug in OpenBSD's shell?  Also, what is meant by "error" in the POSIX text linked to above?

---

Extra bit of info:  The OpenBSD shells will execute the `echo ok` both with and without `set -e`  in the command

```sh
eval ! true || echo ok
```

---

My original code looked like

```sh
set -e
if eval "$string"; then
    echo ok
else
    echo not ok
fi
```

which would *not* output `not ok` with `string=false` using the OpenBSD shells (it would terminate), and I wasn't sure it was by design, by mistake or by misunderstanding, or something else.

Comment: `eval false` generates a non-zero status so I would expect `set -e` to terminate the script at that point. In the case of `!` `set -e` does not apply as `!` statement explicitly checks the exit status.

Comment: @fcbsd Would you expect `eval false` to terminate the script even if it's part of an AND-OR list or a conditional statement? I wouldn't.

Comment: I'm not sure if `set -e` is set if that is the correct behaviour... I agree that it makes sense to not terminate in a conditional statement.

Comment: having played some more, with sh on CentOS 7 - I would say that is intended behaviour for OpenBSD's ksh/sh when using `set -e` so the ` ( )` is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That no other shell needs such workaround is an strong indication that it is a bug in OpenBSD ksh. In fact, ksh93 doesn't show such issue.

That there is a `||` in the command line must avoid the shell exit caused by an return code of 1 on the left side of it.

The error of an **special** built-in shall cause the exit of a non interactive shell [acording to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01) but that is not always true. Trying to `continue` out of a loop is an error, and `continue` is a builtin. But most shells do not exit on:

```
continue 3
```

A builtin that emits a clear error but doesn't exit.

So, the exit on `false` is generated by the `set -e` condition not by the builtin characteristic of the command (`eval` in this case).

The exact conditions on which `set -e` shall exit are quite more fuzzy in POSIX.

Comment: This echoes the response that I got off the OpenBSD mailing list, but with more words, thanks! I'll sort out a proper bug report, and if nothing happens, I'll look at the source code myself.

Answer (score 4):

[sorry if this is not a real answer, I'll update it when I get round to it]

I had a look at the source code, and my conclusions are:

1) It's a bug/limitation, nothing philosophical behind it.

2) The "fix" for it from the portable fork of OpenBSD's ksh (`mksh`) is *very* poor, only making things worse, without really fixing it:

New bug, different from all the other shells:

```
mksh -ec 'eval "false; echo yup"'
yup

bash -ec 'eval "false; echo yup"'
(nothing)
```

Still not really fixed:

```
mksh -ec 'eval "set -e; false" || echo yup'
(nothing)

bash -ec 'eval "set -e; false" || echo yup'
yup
```

You can replace `bash` above with `dash`, `zsh`, `yash`, `ksh93`, etc.